# Format JQuery array for searching

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a list of products, each which have different sizes which will fit different machines. eg.

**product a**

```
size a1 - 
fits-> machine1, machine2, machine3

size a2 - 
fits-> machine4, machine5, machine6
```

**product b**

```
size b1 - 
fits-> machine7, machine8, machine9

size b2 - 
fits-> machine1, machine10, machine11
```

I want people to search by machine number and for it to show which product and size number they need so if somebody searches for `machine1` it would bring up:

```
producta - sizeA1

productb - sizeB2
```

Am I on the right lines or is there a better way to format my array?:

```
producta = {
    "sizeA1": "machine1, machine2, machine3",
    "sizeA2": "machine4, machine5, machine6",
};
productb = {
    "sizeB1": "machine7, machine8, machine9",
    "sizeB2": "machine1, machine10, machine11",
};
```

Comment: You know JQuery is not the programming language, don't you?